# Adding class to the parent of current-post-ancestor / current-menu-parent / current-post-parent

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, customization

Following situation:

I have a drop down menu. At the moment we are located on a single post of the category "Produkt Design"

[image]

Its class in the menu is
`menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category current-post-ancestor current-menu-parent current-post-parent menu-item-145`
The parent to whom I want to apply a special styling, since it is the parent of the active menu entry, has the following classes

`menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-has-children menu-item-151`

How can I make to get a special class to show in parent?

[See demo of the menu here](http://demo.benfluri.com/2014/04/victopack/)

[image]

Comment: I did it using javascript now in the demo page. But a clean php solution would be better

Answer (score 0):

You can add css classes to a menu item in the word press menu graphic interface.
Either add the class to the parent or to the menu item then use css parent.

Comment: well that is the thing, you cannot style something like this ``.menu-parent (ifchildhasclass(current-post-ancestor)){color: red;}``